# How to parallelize Spark/Pyspark function execution on multiple dataframes, without for loop?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parallel-processing

I'm new to Spark and am trying to figure out a more efficient way to write this data processing program. In my code, I have several Pyspark Dataframes `dfA, dfB, dfC` and I need to execute several functions on these dataframes (the functions themselves involve transformations such as joins) and then collect the resulting data at the end.

Currently, my code looks like:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('app_name').getOrCreate()

results = []
dataframes = [dfA, dfB, dfC] 

for df in datframes: 
  x = func1(df)
  y = func2(df) 
  z = func3(df)
  results.append((x, y, z))
```

The internal functions themselves look like:

```
def func1(df): 
   column, table, select_statement = getRelevantSQLBasedOnMetadata(df) # no Spark tranformations here 
   df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
   res = spark.sql(f"""SELECT {select_statement} FROM df a JOIN {table} b ON a.{column}=b.{column}""")
   return res.count() # or some other transformation 

def func2(df): 
   columns = getTableColumns(df) #no Spark transformations here 
   res = []
   for column in columns: 
       where_clause = getWhereClauseFromColumn(column)
       x = spark.sql(f"""SELECT column FROM df WHERE {where_clause}""") 
       res.append(x.count()) #or some other transformation 
   return res
```

Naturally this is very slow and sometimes results in executor memory errors. Does anyone have any suggestions for parallelizing either the for loop or the inner functions? Thanks!

Comment: Likely nothing wrong w/ your loop. The oom might come from the join itself. You should make sure to optimize it.